# What is the difference between "dominant" and "predominant"?

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference (in meaning) between "dominant" and "predominant"?

Comment: http://ielts.studyhorror.com/questions/difference-between-predominant-and-dominant/25

Comment: Questions that can be answered using commonly-available references are off-topic here. Some of the [online resources](http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/2573/what-good-reference-works-on-english-are-available-online)

Comment: We can probably just shut down the entire forum then.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dominant may be more used in influence.

> e.g. newspapers play a dominant role in shaping public opinion

And

Predominant might be used more to mean 'more frequent' or 'more common'.

> e.g. the most predominant colour in this room is beige. However, you could also say the dominant colour in this room is beige - you wouldn't use 'most' in this sentence though.

[Reference](http://www.gingersoftware.com/english-online/spelling-book/confusing-words/dominate-predominant) for "dominant" and "predominant"?

Comment: Not sure what you mean when saying "you wouldn't use 'most' in this sentence", because you just have used "most" in that the sentence. I assume you mean that you wouldn't use "most" with "dominant". I wouldn't use "most" with "predominant" because - according to the definition you yourself have referred to - "predominant" already implies "most".